# MySQL - JOIN based on value of column?

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have two tables:

```
Table "categories"

category  |  parents
1         |  5,4,1
2         |  3,2
```

Column parents is group of numbers divided with comma, so it could be used in query as `IN(parents)`

```
Table "categories_goods"

item | category
10   | 1
12   | 2
```

And I want to export data to third table - there will be all parents for every category. Result should be:

```
Table "categories_goods_all"

item | category
10   | 5
10   | 4
10   | 1
12   | 3
12   | 2
```

I have this solved in PHP, but it is slow when there is 10000 * x of rows in table categories_goods. So I am looking for pure MySQL solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

Demo:
http://rextester.com/CAF76544

Query

```
select
  g.item,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.parents, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) category1
from
  (select 1 n union all
   select 2 union all select 3 union all
   select 4 union all select 5) numbers 
 INNER JOIN categories c 
  on CHAR_LENGTH(c.parents)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(c.parents, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
  inner join categories_goods g
  on c.category=g.category 
order by
  c.category, n
```

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17942691/5234334) to split csv to rows.

Explanation: The `number` table generate number `1`-`5`. You might want to add more rows here for if needed for more `parent`. With its help, you can separate `csv` to columns. Refer the answer URL given above for the same.

Now you just need to do a join to `categories_goods` to fetch `item` corresponding to `parent`

Comment: Thank you, this worked great!! :) Is there any way how to make it to parse any number of values? Now it works with 5. I can manually add select 6 union all ... but could it be infinitely somehow?